# Vue - axios - handling same requests

Tags: vue.js, axios

In my project I've got such structure:
Client page which has sidebar, general client's info and router-view for children views.

routes:

```
{ path: '/clients/:id', component: Client,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        component: ClientReview,
        name: 'client-review'
      },
      {
        path: 'balances',
        component: ClientBalances,
        name: 'client-balances'
      },
      {
        path: 'report',
        component: MainReport,
        name: 'client-report'
      },
```

Client's component (Client.vue):

```
<template>
  <el-row>
    <client-menu></client-menu>
    <el-col class="client-view" :md="{ span: 22, offset: 2}" :sm="{ span: 20, offset: 4}" :xs="{ span: 18, offset: 6}">
      <client-bar></client-bar>
      <transition name="el-zoom-in-center">
        <router-view></router-view>
      </transition>
    </el-col>
  </el-row>
</template>

<script>
import ClientMenu from './ClientMenu.vue'
import ClientBar from './ClientBar.vue'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      loading: false,
    };
  },
  components: {
    'client-menu': ClientMenu,
    'client-bar': ClientBar,
  }

}
</script>
```

ClientBar component (ClientBar.vue):

```
<template>
  <div class="client-bar">
    <el-col :span="18">
      <h3>{{ client.Name }}</h3>
      <h4>{{ client.Address }}</h4>
    </el-col>
    <el-col :span="6" style="text-align: right;">
      <el-button-group>
        <el-button icon="edit" size="small"></el-button>
        <el-button icon="share" size="small"></el-button>
      </el-button-group>
    </el-col>
    <div class="clrfx"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      client: {}
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.loadClient()
  },
  methods: {
    loadClient: function() {
      self = this;
      this.axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8020/clients/'+self.$route.params.id)
        .then(function(response) {
          self.client = response.data;
          self.loading = false;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And I've got ClientReview component, which is root component for clients/:id route and use the same api to load clients information as ClientBar:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <el-row v-loading.body="loading">
      <el-col :span="12">
        <table class="el-table striped">
          <tr>
            <td class="cell">Полное наименование</td>
            <td class="cell">{{ clientInfo.FullName }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="cell">УНП</td>
            <td class="cell">{{ clientInfo.UNP }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="cell">ОКЭД</td>
            <td class="cell">{{ clientInfo.Branch.code }}<br>{{ clientInfo.Branch.name }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="cell">Адрес</td>
            <td class="cell">{{ clientInfo.Address }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="cell">Аналитик</td>
            <td class="cell">{{ clientInfo.Analytic.first_name }} {{ clientInfo.Analytic.last_name }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="cell">Менеджер</td>
            <td class="cell">{{ clientInfo.Manager.first_name }} {{ clientInfo.Manager.last_name }}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </el-col>
      <el-col :span="12">
        <classification-report></classification-report>
      </el-col>
    </el-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ClassificationReport from '../reports/ClassificationReport.vue'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      loading: false,
      clientInfo: {}
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.Client();
  },
  methods: {
    Client: function() {
      self = this;
      self.loading = true;
      self.axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8020/clients/'+self.$route.params.id)
        .then(function(response) {
          self.clientInfo = response.data;
          self.loading = false;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  },
  components: {
    'classification-report': ClassificationReport
  }
}
</script>
```

The problem is when I load page client/:id first time or refresh the page client's data in ClientReview doesn't load. 
The component is rendered (as I see it in Vue Devtools), and both requests to server are sent, but clientInfo object in ClientReview still empty.
Than if I go to balances or report page and after that go to client-review page everything is loaded.
Hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `self` happens to be another reference to the `window` object, and is available in all modules.

Let's walk thru the steps and see why this bug is happening.

1. You load up `client:/id`.
2. The `created` method in `ClientReview` does ajax request, and assigns `self` to `this`.
3. The `mounted` method in `ClientBar` does ajax request, and **re**assigns `self` to `this`. Note that this also changed the `self` variable reference in `ClientReview`.
4. The `ClientReview` ajax finishes and assigns `self.clientInfo = response.data;`. Since `self` is a reference to `ClientBar`, and `ClientBar` does not declare `clientInfo` as a root data property, this assignment does nothing.
5. `ClientBar` ajax finishes and assigns `self.client = response.data;`, which works.
6. You route away from `ClientReview`.
7. You route back to `ClientReview`. Repeat step 2.
8. `ClientReview` successfully renders because `ClientBar` has already rendered, and does not reassign `self`.

The answer is to do `let self = this` instead of `self = this`.

The lesson is **ALWAYS DECLARE YOUR VARIABLES** with `var`, `let` or `const`.